# Get the name of a Column (PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

How can I get the name of the first column out of a table in PostgreSQL?

I know how to get them all but how do I separate the first one from the others ?

```
    public void getColumns(String username, String password, String database, String table){

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+database;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            // Gets the metadata of the database
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();

            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, table, null);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    colummName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                    System.out.println(colummName);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(connection!=null){

        } else {
            window.showNotification("Cannot connect to a Database",Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. The first one is the first one. If the above code works, then the first column is the one which is printed first. If it doesn't work, then tell us what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit hard to understand what it is you're asking, but I think you want the column name from a given index (in this case, you want the first column's name).

Use [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html):

```
int index = 1; //for the first column
String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(index);
```

Note the column indexes are one-based, not zero-based. So first column is 1, second is 2 etc

Comment: thx for your answer , helped me to get the solution i was looking for. Here is what i've done : ArrayList<String> column= new ArrayList<String>(); and in the loop i added : column.add(colummName); to get the first element i did:    System.out.println(column.get(0));

Comment: That will work. But why both adding it to an arrayList? Why not just use the ResultSetMetaData and the getColumnName(index) method? It is essentially an arrayList.